# CakePHP generate a link whose argument parameter is determined by a select input

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

Say I am on a view on my Cake app. E.g. http://myapp.com/controller/action/argument

I am aware of generating a link with the HtmlHelper like so:

```
echo $this->HtmlHelper->link( 'Link title', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction', $parameter) );
```

Now, say I have a dropdown select box with a load of options in it. What's the best way to have the link use the value in the select box as the parameter for the action? Would I need to use jQuery to change the link upon dropdown change?

Comment: Yeah. You should use javascript for it.

Comment: yep, you'd need jQuery, or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrote the CakePHP link as more generic as you can, so using a jQuery function like that:

```
function displayVals() {
    var src = $( "#sel" ).val();
    $('#link').attr('href',src);
}
```

and a HTML part like that:

```
<form action="../">
<select id="sel" name="myDestination">
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">YAHOO</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</option>
</select>
</form>
<a href="" id="link">click</a>
```

your result will be something similar to this this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkfK4/).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by using `jquery`

just use html script block for getting the script inside your html.

```
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock("
    $('#yourSelectBoxId').change(function() {
        var url = '". $this->Html->url(array(
            'controller' => 'mycontroller', 
            'action' => 'myaction', $parameter
        )) ."'; // just setting your url like this.
        // you can proceed further with url 
    })
")
```